# Why Data Table Filling Wrong Column in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

I am creating a data table and filling it's columns as you can see below

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("TraceId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TransactionId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TransactionDate", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(Int64));
    dt.Columns.Add("SenderName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SenderIban", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SenderBank", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ReceiverIban", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ReceiverName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("PayaCycle", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("CycleTime", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("PayId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ReturnCausality", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ReturnId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Rejected", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("AdDate", typeof(string));
```

and then i create a new row and fill its columns in following way

```
    foreach (var item in transactions)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["TraceId"] = item.traceId;
        row["TransactionId"] = item.transactionId;
        row["TransactionDate"] = item.transactionDate;
        row["SenderName"] = item.senderName;
        row["SenderIban"] = item.senderIban;
        row["SenderBank"] = item.senderBank;
        row["Amount"] = Convert.ToInt64(item.amount);
        row["ReceiverIban"] = item.receiverIban;
        row["ReceiverName"] = item.receiverName;
        row["Comment"] = item.comment;
        row["PayaCycle"] = item.payaCycle;
        row["CycleTime"] = item.cycleTime;
        row["PayId"] = item.payId;
        row["ReturnCausality"] = item.returnCausality;
        row["ReturnId"] = item.returnId;
        row["Rejected"] = item.rejected;
        row["AdDate"] = item.adDate;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

and then pass it to my procedure

```
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnString))
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "---------";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InquiryTable", dt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

also you can see my procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateRequestFromKarizInquiry_V2]
@InquiryTable AS [dbo].[PayaInquiryResult] READONLY
AS
BEGIN

--Just For Test
    SELECT * INTO A_Res
    FROM @InquiryTable

END
```

when i select from `A_Res` you can see that first three column has wrong value,it seems that their value has swapped between them...!

[image]

**By the way i'm pretty sure that my Transaction object has correct value for these fields that i am    setting above.**

also you can see my table type structure

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PayaInquiryResult] AS TABLE(
    [TransactionId] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [TraceId] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [Amount] [BIGINT] NULL,
    [SenderName] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [SenderIban] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [SenderBank] [NVARCHAR](20) NULL,
    [ReceiverIban] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [ReceiverName] [NVARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [Comment] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [PayaCycle] [NVARCHAR](20) NULL,
    [CycleTime] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
    [PayId] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ReturnCausality] [NVARCHAR](10) NULL,
    [ReturnId] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
    [Rejected] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
    [AdDate] [VARCHAR](30) NULL
)
```

Comment: Your Create Type has : TransactionId, TransactionDate,TraceId. While you DataTable has TraceId, TransactionId, TransactionDate.

Comment: i'm filling by column's name not index...

Comment: You are passing a DataTable and the order of the rows in the DataTable are filling the database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where was my mistake.
i should have added column exactly according to my table type structure in sql..thanks to @jdweng

```
 var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("TransactionId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TransactionDate", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TraceId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(Int64));
    dt.Columns.Add("SenderName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SenderIban", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SenderBank", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ReceiverIban", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ReceiverName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("PayaCycle", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("CycleTime", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("PayId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ReturnCausality", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ReturnId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Rejected", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("AdDate", typeof(string));
```

**I should have respected the column index**